# How to auto direct to "my web application" from "root (/)" context in JBoss?

Tags: redirect, jboss, contextpath

I am using JBoss 6.0 .

I have deployed my web application: **myApp.ear** under the web-context: "**/test**".
So in browser-url if I type "***http://localhost:8080/test/***", I do get my login page (myLogin.jsp).

Since my WAR exists inside a EAR file, I have specified the context root in the **application.xml** file using a **context-root** element inside of the web module - i.e.

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>myWeb.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/test</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

My question is how to **auto direct** user to my web-app  from "root context"?

I mean if user types "**http://localhost:8080/**", I would expect my web-application's login page to load (instead of JBoss's default ROOT.war's index.html page).

I deleted existing **index.html** from **{JBOSS}\server\default\deploy\ROOT.war** and created a login.jsp there. Now I can see that "login.jsp" is getting invoked when I type http://localhost:8080/.  But I can not redirect user-request to my web-app's login page.

In that login.jsp, I have tried with:
 `<jsp:forward page="/test" />`, but I get error: "HTTP Status 404 - /test".

If I invoke like `<jsp:forward page="/test/myLogin.jsp" />` I still get the same 404 error.

Can any one suggest how to achieve the auto-direct to my web-app from root-context?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to keep index.html in default deploy folder and forward request to your web module.

For example keep following line only in index.html

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=/test/"/>
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer from [Senthil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5709250/1378053) works nice, but user could see the actual redirect done by the browser (page blinks). The redirect can be done also with rewrite [[1](http://jbossweb.jboss.org/modules/rewrite.html), [2](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/rewrite.html)] functionality of the JBoss server, which supports HTTP Redirect with 30x codes (no blink).

You can either add the rewrite to your app directly (`web.xml`, `jboss-web.xml`) and specify the redirect rules in `rewrite.properties` - not shown here.

Or you can modify the server configuration on it's own without touching the original application. I find this solution handy because the application is left intact.

Use case: We use this for [EJBCA](https://www.ejbca.org/) deployment (not our app), it sets it's context root to `/ejbca`. We want to preserve the default deployment process provided by the packaged `ant` script while in the same time we would like to add a redirect from `/` to `/ejbca` as some kind of default, for user friendliness. If user wants to change it, it's done simply by modifying `standalone.xml` without need to redeploy the whole app.

Edit `standalone.xml`:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <rewrite pattern="^/$" substitution="/test" flags="L,QSA,R" />
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: This is really elegant. Fine! Works for me (but xmls="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" in my case)

Comment: I have tried this and ended with the exception - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS018038: Root contexts can not be deployed when the virtual host configuration has the welcome root enabled, disable it and redeploy

Comment: JBoss eAP 7 seems to come with the subsystem urn:jboss:domain:undertow, which needs slightly different configuration. See https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.4/html/configuration_guide/configuring_the_web_server_undertow#configure_the_default_welcome_Web_application

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me on Wildfly 26.1.1 and JBoss EAP 7.4.

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <filters>
            <rewrite name="myfilter" redirect="true" target="/myapp/"/>
        </filters>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" ssl-context="applicationSSC" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <http-invoker http-authentication-factory="application-http-authentication"/>
                <filter-ref name="myfilter" predicate="path('/')"/> 
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <application-security-domains>
            <application-security-domain name="other" security-domain="ApplicationDomain"/>
        </application-security-domains>
    </subsystem>
```

It looks like much but actually is not. My solution shows the default configuration, I just had to add the `<filters>` section and the `<filter-ref>`.

Be aware the `<filters>` section must come above `<server>` otherwise JBoss will complain at startup. This was not documented at https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2996371 but after all I found https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/subsystem/undertow/index.html.

In `jboss-cli` this means:

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=filter/rewrite=myfilter/:add(redirect=true, target=/myapp)
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/filter-ref=myfilter/:add(predicate="path('/')")
```

The automatically generated standalone.xml does not have exactly the same structure as above but works as well.